# Ordering items based on weighted preferences

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

I'm looking to order cars based on their speed, horse power, and 0-60 time based on a person's preference for each category expressed as a percentage.

For example:

- **13%** speed (fastest)
- **50%** horse power (highest)
- **37%** 0-60 time (fastest)

When ordering the cars, a car with high horse power, an average 0-60 time, and low speed would be shown first. However, the car with the highest horse power wouldn't be shown first if it had a low 0-60 time and low speed since horse power only has a 50% weight.

How would I go about solving this? What's this type of problem called?

Comment: This is just an evaluation index, an ordinary function for assess how fit is your car, and then you sort on that function. Trivial.

Comment: @hyprfrcb Thanks for the prompt response. Could you please point me to a resource where I can learn more about evaluation indexes?

Comment: I dont think there is any key resource... it is just part of the science... some call them KPIs, some call them Data Mining, some call them Clustering...